# Create an undefined field Map in Google-Gson for object parsed with ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory

Tags: java, gson

I want to create a Map field which contains all other fields that were not defined in a class to parse.

For instance, having a json

```
{
    "first": "value",
    "second": "value",
    "unknown": "value",
    "undefined": "value"
}
```

And a class would be

```
public class DaClass {

    @SerializedName("first")
    private String mFirst;

    @SerializedName("second")
    private String mSecond;

    @UndefinedMap // This annotation does not exist. I've put it here for an example,
                  // to indicate this is not a regular Map for key "mUndefined", but
                  // rather a map to put unparsed fields to.
    private Map<String, ?> mUndefined;
}
```

Where mUndefined contents would be

```
key="unknown" value="value"
key="undefined" value="value"
```

One idea is to rather create a custom Map type and create TypeAdapterFactory similar to MapTypeAdapterFactory but which uses a parent class fields and exclude `BoundField`s from a parent `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory`, not sure how to do this, seems pretty complex.

```
public class DaClass {

    @SerializedName("first")
    private String mFirst;

    @SerializedName("second")
    private String mSecond;

    private UndefinedMap<String, ?> mUndefined;
}
```

And

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(UndefinedMap.class, new UndefinedMapTypeAdapterFactory());
```

But what the real question is, is there already a support for something similar?

Comment: Could you create a custom serializer/deserializer for the `DaClass` instead?

Comment: @Alexis It can be possible. Not sure how do I do that to achieve what I want. I haven't read about custom deserializers yet. I'll post an update if I'll find out how it is done.

Comment: Was thinking of something like this: https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/efe3057d752c33f9b662 Let me know if it helps :-)

Comment: @Alexis, that's a really good idea, but the drawback is that we have to parse everything manually. My object is a bit complex and contains a Collection of itself as a field, e.g. like `private List<DaClass> mItems`, other Objects with types that have to be deserialized as Gson objects as well, and I want it to use reflection so I don't have to modify the Factory whenever I change the DaClass itself. I'm stuck for an hour now trying to implement this, and that produced lots of code and more potential bug sources.

Comment: I see it was a bad Idea from start. I need the other fields to be parsed as ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory would, without involving my code to parse the defined fields. And also your code puts JsonElements to undefined map. Instead of this I want the java Object, parsed as Google-Gson with ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory would parse. E.g. If the value is a Json Integer, the value must be java.lang.Integer, if the value is Gson Boolean, the value must be a java.lang.Boolean, if the value is JsonObject, the value must be a Map<String, ?>. The JsonElement does not allow to get the type of the value.

Comment: About my code, it can be easily adapted to have a kind of recursive factory method that would return the appropriate object based on the type of the `JsonElement` you're parsing. It was just to roughly illustrate the principle.

Comment: @Alexis, I would appreciate an example of using a factory method based on the `JsonElement` type.

Comment: @AlexisC. `objectFromElement` was what I was really missing. Now based on your Idea i achieved what I wanted. I am iterating over `jObject.entrySet()` and looking for a field based on `Entry` key. If the field is not found, I add it to the undefined map, otherwise I set the field via reflection. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Though your answer is *not exactly* what I've needed to do but it gives a good idea.

Comment: Maybe there's a cleaner way to do this, so I won't post it as a solution. But glad it had helped you a bit though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem as follows (with Gson 2.8.2):

1. Parse the known fields into the class instance (unknown fields are ignored)
2. Turn the json string into a map
3. Remove the known fields from that map
4. Assign the remaining map to the class member

Sample code:

```
    DaClass daClass = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString.toString(), DaClass.class);

    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
    Map<String, Object> mapOfUndefined = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString.toString(), type);

    mapOfUndefined.remove("first");
    mapOfUndefined.remove("second");

    daClass.mUndefined = mapOfUndefined;
```